# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary

I am getting this error

> Mainsection.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Here is my mainsection.js file, I am using API key to iterate the data, I am still not getting the cause of the error. First I had made an array whose name was info and stored all the data in it and then iterated it, Now after using fetchapi, I deleted that array as it was of no use. I don't know whether it was meant to delete or not.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Card from './Card'

export default class Mainsection extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            info:null
        }
    }
async componentDidMount(){
    let Url="https://randomuser.me/api/?inc=gender,name,nat,location,picture,email&results=";
    let data= await fetch(Url);
    let parsedData= await data.json()
    console.log(parsedData);
    this.setState({
         info : parsedData.info
    })

}

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="container mt-5">
                    <div className="row">
                        {this.state.info.map((element) => {
                            return <div className="col-md-4">
                                <Card key={element.email} name={element.name} location={element.location} gender={element.gender} imageUrl={element.picture.medium} />
                            </div>
                        })}

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And here is my card.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Card extends Component {
    render() {
        let {name, location, gender, imageUrl}=this.props
        return (
            <div>
                 <div className="card" style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
            <img src={imageUrl} className="card-img-top" alt="..." />
            <div className="card-body">
                <h5 className="card-title">{name}</h5>
                <p className="card-text">{location}</p>
                <p className="card-text">{gender}</p>
                <a href="/" className="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Please let me I should provide more details

Comment: So console.log info: this.info -  it likely is not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-hill-uxtt0

There are other issues with your code. For example, the name and location are objects and you are directly trying to show it on UI. I have also added code to fix name.

**Mainsection.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Card from "./Card";

export default class Mainsection extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      info: null,
      results: null
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    let Url =
      "https://randomuser.me/api/?inc=gender,name,nat,location,picture,email&results=";
    let data = await fetch(Url);
    let parsedData = await data.json();
    console.log(parsedData);
    this.setState({
      info: parsedData.info,
      results: parsedData.results
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log("results : ", this.state.results);
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container mt-5">
          <div className="row">
            {this.state?.results?.map((element) => {
              return (
                <div className="col-md-4">
                  <Card
                    key={element.email}
                    name={element.name}
                    location={element.location}
                    gender={element.gender}
                    imageUrl={element.picture.medium}
                  />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Card.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Card extends Component {
  render() {
    let { name, location, gender, imageUrl } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="card" style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
          <img src={imageUrl} className="card-img-top" alt="..." />
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">{`${name?.title} ${name?.first} ${name?.last}`}</h5>
            <p className="card-text">{JSON.stringify(location)}</p>
            <p className="card-text">{gender}</p>
            <a href="/" className="btn btn-primary">
              Go somewhere
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It did worked, but in place of name and other details I got an object which is {"street":{"number":3675,"name":"Næstvedvej"},"city":"Kongens Lyngby","state":"Danmark","country":"Denmark","postcode":26603,"coordinates":{"latitude":"-27.8099","longitude":"77.5455"},"timezone":{"offset":"+3:30","description":"Tehran"}}

Comment: yes. name must be working as you expect but I left the location part so that you can fix it on your own.

Comment: Yeah, I will fix it, Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

So, the `API` you are using doesn't response back with an `Array`. But it responses with an `object`, that `object` has 2 `attributes` which are `results` and `info`. as you can see below

```
{
"results": ...
....
....
"info": ...
}
```

and `results` it self is an `Array of objects`, while `info` is just an object.

So yes, you cant use map on object, its only useable on arrays.
Check the response carefully so you can decide what you wanna do.